# How to configure a page to display while server is in planned maintenance in Jboss?

Tags: jboss, custom-error-pages

How to configure in Jboss, when server is in planned maintenance(not completely down), to display an error page? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "down"?  JBoss can't display any pages if it isn't running.

Comment: server swap, planned maintenance, but the Jboss server is still running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Inside JBoss: during the time your application, say myapp.war, is down, you can deploy another myapp.war with just a single HTML/JSP file, displaying that the server is under maintenance. See [Hello, World! Web App](http://www.centerkey.com/jboss/) as an example for a simple web app.
2. If your JBoss runs behind another webserver, such as Apache, you can enable a rewrite during maintenance:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^.*$ http://yourdoman.com/maintenance-info.html [L,R]
   ```

We use the second option because sometimes we also shutdown the JBoss instance.