# Need help configuring a maintenance page running 2 JBoss App Servers behind Mod_cluster

Tags: apache, jboss, mod-cluster, maintenance-mode

I have 2 Jboss app servers running configured with port offset of 100 the first is listening on 8009 and second on 8109.  They are configured to talk to the apache mod cluster on port 4221.

My Apache server is listening on port 8000 for app requests.

I read several posts saying you need to configure the .htaccess file and add in:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://localhost:*/SiteDown.html [L,R]
```

But according to the Apache official documents they say using the .htaccess is not the correct way to configure this as this can have a performance impact.
They recommended to use the Directory tag.

My question is How do I setup the  tag and where do I put it in the config file so that when I want to have a maintenance page displayed instead of serving up the app pages?

Here is the config I have in the conf file for mod_cluster

## MOD_CLUSTER_ADDS

```
<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 127.0.0.1:4221
  Maxsessionid 100
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:4221>
    <Location />
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AllowDisplay on
    ServerAdvertise off
    #ServerAdvertise on http://127.0.0.1:4221
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    #AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
    #AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
    EnableMCPMReceive on

    <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0
    </Location>
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean,you are having below setup :

```
Client - Apache(mod_cluster) - JBoss node1+(cluster)+node2
```

So,whenever you have any maintenance over the backend Jboss nodes;then Jboss should not serve any request,Instead It should show some maintenance page? Is that correct?

Comment: If such is the scenario then I do not see any way other than what is suggested in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320791/how-to-configure-a-page-to-display-while-server-is-in-planned-maintenance-in-jbo?rq=1]